# What is impact by deleting android app from firebase

Tags: firebase

I want to delete android app and create a new app in firebase project to change package name, buy I don't know what impact is by delete app.
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7047853?hl=en
I found this doc about delete firebase. Is there any impact else after delete app?
appreciate for answer.

Answer (score 0):

The app is simply removed from the project.  That's all.  Nothing else in the project will change.  You can then create a new app, get a new configuration file for it, and start using it immediately.

Comment: It may seem dumb, but may the app crash if the project is deleted from Firebase?